# what is the purpose of differentiation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm recently learning about differentiation and I have no idea why its important. All I know is that has something to do with rate of change and acceleration over time?
I understand how but I'm really struggling to understand why we do it, it doesn't make sense!
Can someone give a real life example of how and why differentiation is important

Comment: If you know the rate of change over time, you can predict the future. Sounds pretty powerful to me. Practically, if you know how distance changes over time, you can find speed and acceleration using differentiation.

Comment: If you tell us which field you are interested in (physics/computer science/economics/social sciences/music...), then someone could answer you specifically how differentiation pops up in these fields. 
Otherwise, here is a famous math teacher talking about the big picture of derivatives: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_I-CUOc_bk

Comment: If you drive a car you probably often check the derivative of the distance over time.